# Vue Render span as part of a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Vue newb warning. I'm redoing my personal site(done in react) in Vue just as an exercise. I have a list of things in a js file that I display on the home page:

```
export default [
"i did x",
"i did y",
<span onClick={() => window.open('www.google.com', '_blank')}>this is a link to google</span>,
"i did x",
]

// in react
<div>
  {itemList.map(item => <div>{item}</div>)}
</div>
```

In react I'm able to import this file, loop through it and display each item as desired(text is text and hyperlinks become linked spans). In Vue, when I import the list, the span items come through in a way I'm unfamiliar with:
[image]

which makes it so

```
// In Vue
<div v-for="item in listItems" :key="item">{{item}}</div>
```

doesn't quite work as expected. I can do a bunch of logic in a hacky way to make this work, but

##Question (a): Is there a different way to import this list to that it comes through in a way that allows me to render each item as they're laid out in the list

##Question (b): Is there in general a better way to do this using the object structure that is given to me in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recommand to structure your data a bit different, i.e. like this:

```
export default [
  {
    value: "i did x",
  },
  {
    value: "i did y",
  },
  {
    value: "this is a link to google",
    onClickCallback: () => window.open('www.google.com', '_blank')
  },
  {
    value: "i did x",
  }
]
```

With this data you are more flexible and the rendering you can do similar to this:

```
<div v-for="item in listItems" :key="item.value">
  <span @click="item.onClickCallback">
    {{ item.value }}
  </span>
</div>
```

If you don't want a span around each element, you can also do:

```
<div v-for="item in listItems" :key="item.value">
  <template v-if="!item.onClickCallback">
    {{ item.value }}
  </template>
  <span v-else @click="item.onClickCallback">
    {{ item.value }}
  </span>
</div>
```